# Can visiting people who are in an invalid marriage cause scandal?

Tags: catholicism, scandal

Is there a catholic teaching or guidance on whether it is OK to visit and sleep over at someone's house who is not in a valid marriage?

Can this act show the approval of their marriage and create a sin of scandal?

For example: validly married couple with their children visiting grandma who is invalidly married with her partner(from a Catholic perspective)?